# receive JSON array data from fetch or axios.get VueJS

Tags: vue.js, axios, pusher

I am going mental. So I have the code below. When I run it as is, I get

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'URL' from origin 'http://localhost:8000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

If I remove the CORS header I get the same error. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I will tell you if I curl the URL it works fine. What am I missing here.

Also, I have tried this using both axios.get AND fetch so I am open to both solutions.

```
getRoomUserCount: function () {
            return axios
                .get('URL', {
                    responseType: "json",
                });
        },
```

What it SHOULD return is an array of data, then using the code below I grab the array

```
mounted: function () {
        this.roomUserCount = this.getRoomUserCount();
    },
```

Comment: The question doesn't contain enough data, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . "If I remove the CORS header I get the same error" - where did you remove it, and how? The question doesn't show it. It's unknown what's the setup. In Vue CLI there is `proxy` config that provides a way to avoid CORS problems.

Answer (score 0):

CORS policy is ALWAYS server related. You cannot change anything on your client-side to change that.

Enable CORS on your server to fix this.